# aspnet_regsql error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to run aspnet_sqlreg on my local database (on my machine).

```
aspnet_regsql -ssadd -sstype c -d "computername\localSqlserveNname" -E
```

And after it says "Start adding sesson state.", it says that, "An error has occured.... A network-related or instance-spcific eror occurred while establishing a connetion to SQL server.  The server was not found or was not accessible."  But, I am pretty sure i entered the correct name of the server and database.

Has anyone have similar error?

Comment: Have you checked whether your local SQL server engine is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

the error is on the name

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -ssadd -sstype c -d DATABASENAME -E
```

where `DATABASENAME` is the name of your new database, eg try something like **"SessionStateDB"**

```
  aspnet_regsql.exe -ssadd -sstype c -d SessionStateDB -E
```

Comment: Ah, I got it.  I had to change the name in Named Pipes.

Comment: I took out the default SQL Server name from the  Pipe Name field on sql server confi manager.  I had it as \\.\SQL2008_Local\pipe\sql\query and it worked when I took out "SQL2008_Local" part out.